# How to calculate image size for splash screen of a particular android device

Tags: android, pixel, dpi, splash-screen

I set a single image (640x960) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.imagetest.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/launch_image"
        android:scaleType="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice the scaleType is "center" which according to documentation means no scaling. When running on Nexus 5x, this image looks a lot bigger than the screen and is only partially displayed.

I read about android not using resolution directly. Then the question is how to calculate the size of an image that should fit the screen of a particular android device without scaling.

I understand Nine Patch image can be used to create splash images that will not distort the portion of image that should not be scaled. This question is partly for myself to better understand how image pixels relate to the screen of an actual device, and if using Nine Patch image is the only way to guarantee that the splash images will work on android devices of any screen dimensions.

Many thanks

Comment: In which density-folder you are putting this image ?

Comment: As if you are putting image only in one folder e.g. xhdpi, android will re-scale this image according to it's density. So, image will look smaller in hdpi screen and larger in xxhdpi and xxxhdpi screens.

Comment: Good question. I only had the image in drawable. Why would that make the 640x960 image look larger than the screen of Nexus 5x?

Answer (score 0):

scaleType [centerInside](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) should do the trick without having to make calculations in code

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/launch_image"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

Comment: Thanks NathaZ but part of the question was to understand why a 640x960 image shows up larger on Nexus 5x wihch has a screen resolution of 1080x1920. I know image resolution doesn't translate to that of the screen. But I'd like to understand how these two relate to each other.

Comment: Why are you using app:layout_behavior on a splash screen?